# how to search recipe based on important ingredients ? java android

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I want to search recipe which match with shopping list items and it will suggest recipe to user based on most important ingredients like in Banana MilkShake {milk and banana} could make banana milkshake alone {sugar and vanilla} are optional,if I add items on shopping list like {banana,milk} it will search recipe on the basis of these ingredients rather  {banana,milk,sugar and vanilla} 
**for example:**

```
Banana Milk Shake Ingredients:

**Ingredient Name                
  1.banana                         (important)
  2.milk                           (important)
  3.vanilla                        (optional/not important)
  4.sugar                          (optional/not important) 

**Shopping List**
```

- banana
- milk
- egg
- rice

We could also make Banana Milkshake without sugar and vanilla so important ingredients will be milk and banana.

```
public class Ingredient implements Serializable{

    private String name;
    private String quantity;

    public  Ingredient(){

    }

    public Ingredient(String name,String quantity){
        this.name=name;
        this.quantity=quantity;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

}
```

and my working code:

```
public Set<Recipe> searchByIngredient(List<ShoppingList> shop, List<Recipe> list) {
     int matchedItems = 0;
     Set<Recipe> result = new HashSet<Recipe>();
     for (Recipe rn : list) {
          boolean recipeMatched = false;

          for (ShoppingList r : shop) {

               for (int i = 0; i < rn.getIngre().size(); i++) {
                    if (rn.getIng(i).contains(r.getName())) {
                        matchedItems++;

                        int temp = matchedItems;

                        if(temp >= 2){
                            result.add(rn);
                            recipeMatched = true;
                        }

                    }
                    if (recipeMatched)
                        break;
               }

               if (recipeMatched)
                    break;
          }
          matchedItems = 0;
     }
     return result;
}

public class Recipe implements Serializable{

    private  String instructions;
    private String recName;
    private String image;
    private List<Ingredient> ing = new ArrayList<Ingredient>();

    public Recipe(){

    }
    public Recipe(String item,String quan){
        this.ing.add(new Ingredient(item, quan));
    }


    public List<Ingredient> getIngre(){
        return ing;
    }
    public String getIng(int i){

        return ing.get(i).toString();
    }
    public void setIngredients(List<Ingredient> item){
        this.ing = item;
    }

    public String getRecName() {
        return recName;
    }

    public void setRecName(String recName) {
        this.recName = recName;
    }

    // @Override
    public String toString() {
        return recName;
    }

    public String getInstructions() {
        return instructions;
    }

    public void setInstructions(String instructions) {
        this.instructions = instructions;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @JeremyGordon  i want to search recipe which match with shopping list items and it will suggest recipe to user based on  most important ingredients like in Banana MilkShake  {milk and banana} could make banana alone {sugar and vanilla} are optional,if I add items on shopping list like {banana,milk} it will search recipe on the basis of these ingredients rather i will add {banana,milk,sugar and vanilla}

Comment: You probably want to do something like give each element in the recipe a degree of importance, and then calculate a score for each potential match.  Things get more complicated if you want try to handle substitutions, either explicitly in the recipe itself, or by some set of rules.

Comment: @ChrisStratton how to give this degree of importance? can you modify my code

Comment: @ChrisStratton how to give this degree of importance? can you modify my code

Comment: Add a field to Ingredient, set and examine values.  You will have to do this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments. You could add another variable to your Ingredient class. Like this:

```
public class Ingredient implements Serializable{

    private String name;
    private String quantity;
    private boolean isImportant;

    public  Ingredient(){

    }

    public Ingredient(String name,String quantity){
        this.name=name;
        this.quantity=quantity;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public boolean getIsImportant() {
        return isImportant;
    }

    public void setIsImportant(boolean isImportant) {
        this.isImportant= isImportant;
    }

}
```

Then you could check in the recipe if all the important ingredients are present or not.

Comment: I tried that but instead of boolean i had assigned weights value to ingredient like value 1 for unimportant and value 2 for important @EricB.

Comment: Assigning weights is a good idea, when you have more than 2 values. But if you have just 2 values like 1 and 2, boolean will suffice. Then again, it's totally up to you.

Comment: So how to use these weights ? like if i have (ingredients) banana which have weight 5 and milk weight 4 and so on [5 to 1] i will assigns these weights .. so all weights are sum up? @EricB.

Comment: It depends. According to your original post, you problem was to identify an ingredient as important and unimportant, this case can be handled with boolean. Before giving each ingredient a degree of importance that is weights, ask yourself, what benefit will you get from doing this? what are you trying to achieve by assigning weights which cannot be achieved through boolean?