# how to assign weight value to arraylist items? java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arraylist and i wanted to assign weight value to each arraylist item then sum up their weights like milk weight is 5 sugar weight is 3 and so on.
So what is the formula which returns me sum of these weights?

```
List<Ingredient> ing = new ArrayList<Ingredient>();



public class Ingredient {

    private String name;
    private String quantity;

  public  Ingredient(){

    }

    public Ingredient(String name,String quantity){
        this.name=name;
        this.quantity=quantity;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }


}
```

Comment: This isn't clear - the "formula" is literally just the sum.

Comment: i have no idea how to treat weight value can you give me suggestion? @OliverCharlesworth

Comment: Why not just add a `weight` field to `Ingredient` and then use that when calculating total weight?

Answer (score 1):

So first of all you need to make a field called weight for your Ingredient class. Similar to what you did for quantity.

```
private int weight;

public Ingredient(String name,String quantity,int weight){
        this.name=name;
        this.quantity=quantity;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

public void setWeight(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }
```

I will assume you will set that through the constructor.
To sum them just loop through the list:

```
int sum = 0;  
for( Ingredient i : ing){
    sum+=i.getWeight();
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid the quantity *is* the weight ;)  For sugar anyway.  For milk you can guess it's volume but usually sugar is measured in weight.  The question is quite unclear.

Comment: Hehe, ok then you you don't need to modify the class anymore. Working now?

Comment: thanks limbo but i wanted to search recipe based on ingredient weight \
     `for (Recipe rn : list) {
          boolean recipeMatched = false;

          for (ShoppingList r : shop) {

               for (int i = 0; i < rn.getIngre().size(); i++) {
                    if (rn.getIng(i).contains(r.getName())) {
                        matchedItems++;

                        int temp = matchedItems;

                        if(temp >= 2){
                            result.add(rn);`

Comment: can you add this code to the question? I am not sure I understand what you want.

Comment: i wanted to search recipe based on ingredient weight which recipe have higher value of weight suggested to user (stackoverflow.com/questions/37575625/…) please go to this link and see my recipe search method and recipe class @limbo

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to create an ArrayList of Ingredients? If yes, then you will better to create a separate method in your Main class which will handle the calculation of total weight. See the code below:

```
public class Main {
    private static int totalWeight(ArrayList<Ingredient> list) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (Ingredient i : list) {
            sum += i.getWeight();
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Ingredient> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Ingredient a = new Ingredient("Onion", 2, 1);
        Ingredient b = new Ingredient("Potatoes", 3, 2);
        list.add(a);
        list.add(b);
        int totalWeightOfAllProducts = totalWeight(list);
        System.out.println(totalWeightOfAllProducts);
    }
}
```

Do not forget to add weight property in your Ingredient class!

Comment: i wanted to search recipe based on ingredient weight which recipe have higher value of weight suggested to user (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37575625/how-to-search-recipe-based-on-important-ingredients-java-android) please go to this link and see my recipe search method and recipe class